# Up Down arrow is not coming for firefox of tagfield component

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs

I found one very weird bug in extJS tag field. After using tagfild I am not able to see up-down arrow of field to see selected componet in tagfield.

I created a fiddler, please open fiddler in chrome and firefox and see the difference.

Here is the link for fiddle.
[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/23tg)
Red circle in image is what I am asking for in firefox.
[image]

Can anybody give me some idea.

Comment: I can't see the up-down arrows either on Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 in macOS, which version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit) in windows 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your **growMax** property **from 5 to 35** and it should be fixed.

```
  Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
  renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
  title: 'Sci-Fi Television',
  height: 200,
  width: 300,

  items: [{
      xtype: 'tagfield',
      fieldLabel: 'Select a Show',
      store: shows,
      displayField: 'show',
      valueField: 'id',
      growMax  : 35,
      queryMode: 'local',
      filterPickList: true,

  }]
```

});

It is **not possible for Firefox to draw scrollbars** when the size of the element **height is smaller than 34 pixels**.

I've tried **Safari and Chrome for MacOS** and they also **don't show the scrollbar in the example you posted**.

You can see the scrollbars in the screenshot as soon as the height of the element changes to a value equal or greater than 34 pixels, once it drops below that value (33px in the picture #2) is not longer being shown.
[image]

[image]

I hope this helps to solve your problem.

Comment: But I do not need that big of field height

Comment: The solution would be to override the field's template and include your own scrolling control, handle the click event and scroll the view yourself, it is not a simple task though, but not impossible to achieve.

Comment: Ya.. I am using this as a temporary solution. But lets see if I able to get the correct solution. Thanks for answer